# How can I access SQLyog community through netbeans and insert a query in it? my code is Here below

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, netbeans, sqlyog

I have added Apache tomcat in libraries and all my connect are correct I want to insert data in sqlylog through the html page. What's wrong in my code I have     doubts about insert query and its file.

```
 public class myservlet extends HttpServlet {

class dbconn {

    Connection c1 = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    private final String ac;
    private final String aaa;

    dbconn() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            c1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher", "root", "abcde");

        } catch (Exception cnfe) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
            System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
            System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");
        }
        try {
            st = (Statement) c1.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Statement Created Successfully");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");

        }
        if (c1 != null) {
            System.out.println("Hooray! We connected to the database!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("We should never get here.");
        }
        String query = "INSERT INTO teacher1 (id,name) " 
                + "VALUES (" + 1 + ", '" + aaa + "')";       // insert query is this
    }
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet myservlet</title>"); 
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body >");

        out.println("<h1>Servlet myservlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        String name = request.getParameter("firstname");
        out.println("<h2>" + name + "</h2>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

    public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}
```

index.jsp

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
     <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <form action="myservlet"  method="GET"    >

        First name:<br> 
        <input type="text" name="firstname"/> 
        <br> 
        Last name:
        <br> 
        <input type="text" name="lastname" /> 
        <br><br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on. Sqlyog is a SQL client program just like a tomcat servlet is. Please [edit] your question to give more details. Please don't delay, or your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: you have a lot of things you should to change it first aaa is not initialized second you what error you get?

Comment: youcef can you correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have added Apache tomcat in libraries and all my connect is correct I want to insert data in sqlylog through the html page. What's wrong in my code I have doubts about insert query and its file.

**myservlet.java**

```
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class myservlet extends HttpServlet {

    class dbconn {

        Connection c1 = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        private final String ac;
        private final String aaa;

        dbconn() {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                c1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher", "root", "abcde");

            } catch (Exception cnfe) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
                System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
                System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");
            }
            try {
                st = (Statement) c1.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Statement Created Successfully");
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");

            }
            if (c1 != null) {
                System.out.println("Hooray! We connected to the database!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("We should never get here.");
            }
            String query = "INSERT INTO teacher1 (id,name) "
                    + "VALUES (" + 1 + ", '" + aaa + "')";       // insert query is this
        }
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet myservlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body >");

            out.println("<h1>Servlet myservlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            String name = request.getParameter("firstname");
            out.println("<h2>" + name + "</h2>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

---

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <form action="myservlet"  method="GET"    >

            First name:<br> 
            <input type="text" name="firstname"/> 
            <br> 
            Last name:
            <br> 
            <input type="text" name="lastname" /> 
            <br><br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```